# Rails Active Record Query for Double Nested Joins with a Select Call

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, activerecord-relation

I have the following schema:

Photos `has many` Groups `has many` Users.

I am using this Rails server as a backend to an iOS application and constantly need to push out notifications to all involved users of a group when a photo is added.

I problem is finding the least expensive query to resolve only the `User.ids` affected.

So far I have

```
    Photo.find(1).groups.joins(:users)
```

I know that I have to put a select argument after this, but can't figure out the syntax for the life of me.

Given a photo, I am looking for the most efficient way to find a collection of the affected user id's.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: `Group.where(photo_id: 1).users.collect{|u| puts u.id}`  as Photo has_many groups so groups belongs_to photo and gorups table has photo_id as foreign key so please try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users_id = []   
Group.where(photo_id: 1).users.collect{|u| users_id << u.id}  
puts users_id
```

As Photo `has_many` groups, so, groups `belongs_to` photo and groups table has `photo_id` as foreign key .

So, please try this.

Answer (score 1):

In your Photo model, you can have another associations called users

```
has_many :group_users, :through => :groups, :source => :users
```

Then you can find the users by the following code

```
@photo = Photo.includes([:group_users]).where("photos.id = ?", 1).first
@affected_users = []
@photo.group_users.map {|user| @affected_users << user.id}
```

Now the `@affected_users` contains all the user ids.