# How to query double nested resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models: ImpactEvaluation, Site, MvPlan.

```
 ImpactEvaluation has_many Sites  
 Site has_one MvPlan
```

In one line of code in my model for ImpactEvaluation, I want to be able to query all the MvPlans that fall under this single Impact Evaluation. Meaning it would have to check all the sites under that impact evaluation, then all the MvPlans with the same site id. what is the most elegant way to query this in rails syntax?

I tried doing the solution posted here: [Rails Active Record Query for Double Nested Joins with a Select Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691097/rails-active-record-query-for-double-nested-joins-with-a-select-call)  but it is failing. I am trying these commands currently in my console.

```
> mv_plans_id = []
> Site.where(impact_evaluation_id: 4).mv_plans.collect{|u| mv_plans_id << u.id} puts mv_plans_id  
> SyntaxError: (irb):16: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `has_many :through?`

```
class ImpactEvaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sites
  has_many :mv_plans, through: :sites
end
```

After that you should able to simply call `ImpactEvaluation.find(4).mv_plans`

See [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: should it be has_many although each site only has one mv_plan? each impact evaluation will technically have many mv plans because each one has multiple sites... unsure about this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Site.where(impact_evaluation_id: 4).each do { |site| mv_plans_id << site.mv_plan.pluck(:id) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mv_plans_id=ImpactEvaluation.find(4).sites.map(&:mvplan_id)
```